# Datatype conversion from Pyspark to java

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

We have used case where we need to pass a column with datatype `array<struct<key:string,value:binary>>` to Java function from Databricks job(pyspark) and then read values in java code but the problem is I m not able pass the datatype to Java. If anyone has any idea please share. Thanks

Comment: At the end of the day you will need a manner to serialize/marshall the data for transfer. The deserialization/unmarshalling routine on the Java side can be implemented many ways. An array of an object that has two properties, `key:string, value:binary`, is a pretty standard thing to reproduce in Java. Perhaps try serializing the data as JSON or XML and deserializing into a corresponding Java type.